# ConcurrentSkipListMap firstKey() throws NoSuchElementException even though it contains data

Tags: java, multithreading, nosuchelementexception, concurrentskiplistmap

I wrote a small application that receives data from a web socket, which I store in static ConcurrentSkipListMap.
The application initially creates a new thread where it runs infinitely while loop calling ConcurrentSkipListMap.firstKey(). After a while, this call throws a NoSuchElementException, even though the ConcurrentSkipListMap contains data.
[break point in catch block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ep9AD.png)
Example of my application:

I have cacher class that contains websocket implementation and NavigableMap init:

```
package solvethat.net.triobot.Example;

import com.binance.api.client.BinanceApiCallback;
import com.binance.api.client.BinanceApiClientFactory;
import com.binance.api.client.domain.event.DepthEvent;
import com.binance.api.client.domain.market.OrderBook;
import com.binance.api.client.domain.market.OrderBookEntry;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NavigableMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap;

public class AskCacher {

private long updateId;
private final BinanceApiClientFactory factory;

public AskCacher() {
    factory = BinanceApiClientFactory.newInstance();
    initAsks();
    runWebsocket();
}

/**
 * Init data getting order book snapshot
 */
private void initAsks() {
    try {
        OrderBook orderBook = factory.newRestClient().getOrderBook("btcusdt".toUpperCase(), 10);
        updateId = orderBook.getLastUpdateId();
        NavigableMap<Double, Double> asks = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>(Comparator.naturalOrder());
        for (OrderBookEntry ask : orderBook.getAsks()) {
            asks.put(Double.parseDouble(ask.getPrice()), Double.parseDouble(ask.getQty()));
        }
        StaticData.ask = asks;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void runWebsocket() {
    factory.newWebSocketClient().onDepthEvent("btcusdt", new BinanceApiCallback<>() {
        /**
         * Set ask price and call analysis method
         */
        @Override
        public void onResponse(DepthEvent depthEvent) {
            if (depthEvent.getFinalUpdateId() > updateId) {
                updateId = depthEvent.getFinalUpdateId();
                updateOrderBook(depthEvent.getAsks());
            }
        }

        /**
         * Just print err message
         */
        @Override
        public void onFailure(final Throwable cause) {
            System.err.println(cause.getMessage());
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Updates an order book (asks) with a delta received from the server.
 * Whenever the qty specified is ZERO, it means the price should was removed from the order book.
 */
private void updateOrderBook(List<OrderBookEntry> orderBookDeltas) {
    for (OrderBookEntry orderBookDelta : orderBookDeltas) {
        Double price = Double.parseDouble(orderBookDelta.getPrice());
        BigDecimal qty = new BigDecimal(orderBookDelta.getQty());
        if (qty.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0) {
            // qty=0 means remove this level
            StaticData.ask.remove(price);
        } else {
            StaticData.ask.put(price, Double.parseDouble(orderBookDelta.getQty()));
        }
    }

    // Print best ask to see if cacher is alive
    System.out.println("btc-usdt best ask: " + StaticData.ask.firstKey());

    // Edit map length
    if (StaticData.ask.size() > 10) {
        StaticData.ask.tailMap((Double) StaticData.ask.keySet().toArray()[10], true).clear();
    }
}}
```

Then infinite loop:

```
package solvethat.net.triobot.Example;
public class InfiniteLoop {

public void loopProcess() {
    Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer();
    while (true) {
        analyzer.analyze(StaticData.ask.firstEntry());
    }
}}
```

And analyzer class:

```
package solvethat.net.triobot.Example;

import java.util.Map;

public class Analyzer {

    public void analyze(Map.Entry<Double, Double> entry) {

        StaticData.AnalyzeObject analyzeObject = new StaticData.AnalyzeObject();
        analyzeObject.setBestAsk(entry.getKey());

        if (analyzeObject.getBestAsk() > 50000) {
            System.out.println("It is a good price!!");
        }
    }

}
```

Static data model:

```
package solvethat.net.triobot.Example;

import java.util.NavigableMap;

public class StaticData {
    public static NavigableMap<Double, Double> ask;

    public static class AnalyzeObject {

        double bestAsk;

        public double getBestAsk() {
            return bestAsk;
        }

        public void setBestAsk(double bestAsk) {
            this.bestAsk = bestAsk;
        }
    }
}
```

Main class for example run:

```
package solvethat.net.triobot.Example;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        new AskCacher();
        new Thread(new InfiniteLoop()::loopProcess).start();
    }
}
```

The example only shows how the application is composed, but I was not able to use it to raise an error but I opened my repo as public:
https://github.com/Sick-E/TrioBot

Can anyone please help me?
Thank you.
Tomas

Comment: Please include the code and the error message/stacktrace in the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm afraid that if I copied only part of the code, the problem wouldn't occur. I did my git repo as public: https://github.com/Sick-E/TrioBot

Comment: There is some advice on creating a minimal, reproducible example here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @TomášSýkora Does your breakpoint stops all thread or just one? I bet those values were added while debugger was kicking in. I suggest you switch to using `firstEntry` - it does not throw exception

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your code with something like that (no exception handling is required)

```
Optional.ofNullable(trio.getThirdPair().getBids().firstEntry())
  .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
  .ifPresent(trio.getTrioAnalysis()::setBidThird);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help !! It seems to work but i have to let the app run longer to be sure.

Comment: The code does not throw an exception, but it still happens that firstEntry() is null even though the map is full of data and therefore the field is not filled. I'll leave Optional there for now and I'll try to figure out why the data isn't visible in this call.

Comment: Amy chance that reference to the map is being updated and field is not volatile?

Comment: I already have a volatile keyword in the ConcurrentSkipListMap instance declaration, unfortunately the error is repeated.

Comment: Since I did not find a solution in accordance with ConcurrentSkipListMap, I did a workaround. In the object that ConcurrentSkipListMap contains, I created a field for the best price which I update every time when the order book is updated. So now I don't have to ask ConcurrentSkipListMap for anything in the thread and the error doesn't appear.